# Destroy object in std::vector

Tags: c++, memory, allocator

I wan't to be able to destroy any object without loosing memory:

```
from:
`--------+--------+--------`
| item 1 | item 2 | item 3 |
`--------+--------+--------`
to:
`--------+--------+--------`
| item 1 | empty  | item 3 |
`--------+--------+--------`
```

Used `std::vector<T>::erase` is what comes closest to it, but it doesn't allow me to acces the the old "memory":

```
`--------+--------`
| item 1 | item 3 |
`--------+--------`
```

I tryed to use `std::allocator_traits<T>`, but i didn't figured out how to use it to compile:

```cpp
using allocator = std::allocator_traits<type>;
using alloc_type = std::allocator_traits<type>::allocator_type;

class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(int i) : m_i(i) {}
        ~MyClass() = default;
    private:
        int m_i;
};

int main()
{

    std::vector<MyClass, allocator> vec;

    vec.emplace_back(0);
    // destroy the object but don't rearrange
    allocator::destroy(alloc_type, std::addressof(vec[0]));
}
```

> This code doesn't compile

Comment: `std::vector` is a contiguous container, you can't have empty holes in it. Consider using `std::vector<std::optional<MyClass>>` to allow elements to be nullable to represent "holes" or missing elements.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This looks like a ill-problem. Explain what you're trying to achieve because there is likely a better/cleaner solution than what you're trying to do.

Comment: When a program doesn't compile, the first step is to read the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have destroyed objects in a vector. The vector will eventually destroy all elements and if any are already destroyed, then behaviour will be undefined.

Instead of a vector of `MyClass`, you *could* use a vector of `std::aligned_storage` and handle the construction and destruction of the `MyClass` objects onto the storage yourself. But I don't recommend that because it can be quite challenging and trivial mistakes will lead to undefined behaviuour.

If your goal is to represent a "no value" state, then there is a template wrapper for such purpose in the standard library: `std::optional`. I.e. you could use `std::vector<std::optional<MyClass>>`.